# Android Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'PackageList'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Cannot resolve symbol 'PackageList'

I am getting this error once I open the android folder in my newly generated react-native project.

The steps to recreate it for me is to make the expo project:
expo init my-app

Then eject the project:
Expo eject

And then I go into the android folder and open android\app\src\main\java\Android\Screen\MainActivity.java

and I get the bug.

any help would be much appreciated.[Image of error in the android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maoKu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by creating a new package (right click on your java folder and select new -> package), give it any name.
Within the package create a java class called PackageList
within PackageList paste the following code:

```
package com<NameOfYourProject>;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainPackageConfig;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class PackageList {
  private Application application;
  private ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost;
  private MainPackageConfig mConfig;

  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost) {
    this(reactNativeHost, null);
  }

  public PackageList(Application application) {
    this(application, null);
  }

  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost, MainPackageConfig config) {
    this.reactNativeHost = reactNativeHost;
    mConfig = config;
  }

  public PackageList(Application application, MainPackageConfig config) {
    this.reactNativeHost = null;
    this.application = application;
    mConfig = config;
  }

  private ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return this.reactNativeHost;
  }

  private Resources getResources() {
    return this.getApplication().getResources();
  }

  private Application getApplication() {
    if (this.reactNativeHost == null) return this.application;
    return this.reactNativeHost.getApplication();
  }

  private Context getApplicationContext() {
    return this.getApplication().getApplicationContext();
  }

  public ArrayList<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(mConfig)
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you have to do this?

Comment: @sindre -Since the class was not found I had to create it, I wasn't sure it's gonna work, but then boom it worked.

Comment: If you have things set up correctly, react-native cli will generate `PackageList.java` as part of the gradle build process. make sure you have `apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)` in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do a gradle sync (and build) first - the build will fail, but create `PackageList` for you (in e.g. `android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java`

Similarly, it creates a `BuildConfig.java`

Answer (score 2):

I have to run my project, and my issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I am Totally agree with above answer.

You can solve this by creating a new package (right click on your java folder and select new -> package), give it any name. Within the package create a java class called PackageList.

But in the above code, on the following line

`return this.reactNativeHost.getApplication();`
I get some error, like

> Blockquote error: getApplication() has protected access in ReactNativeHost return this.reactNativeHost.getApplication();

So, to resolve this, this is my modified PackageList Class.

```js
package packagelist;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainPackageConfig;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PackageList {
    private Application application;
    private ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost;
    private MainPackageConfig mConfig;

    public PackageList(Application application) {
        this(application, null);
    }

    public PackageList(Application application, MainPackageConfig config) {
        this.application = application;
        this.reactNativeHost = null;
        this.mConfig = config;
    }

    private Resources getResources() {
        return this.application.getResources();
    }

    private Context getApplicationContext() {
        return this.application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public ArrayList<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new MainReactPackage(mConfig)
        ));
    }
}
```

Hope, this will help someone. :)

Comment: Quick note: - Saying "I am Totally agree with above answer." or "But in the above code" can be meaningless. Answers can be arranged by 4 different criteria that a user can choose and still can mean different arrangements based on the number of answers and their status. For example the default arrangement is 'Highest Score' so the answers will auto change as they are up/down voted, your answer may well be at the top. If you want to reference another answer use the name of the person who posted the answer.

Comment: Okay, I understand, will change as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this on version 0.3.1 of @react-native-masked-view/masked-view on react-native v0.67.5. Downgrading to v0.2.9 works as a temporary solution.